# Install script doesn't execute

Tags: module, configuration, install-script

I'm trying to create a new attribute, but my install script does not run.

etc/config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Namespace_ShippingPrices>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_ShippingPrices>
</modules>
<global>
    ...
    <resources>
        <namespace_shippingprices_setup>
            <setup>
               <module>Namespace_ShippingPrices</module>
               <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </namespace_shippingprices_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

`sql/namespace_shippingprices_setup/install-0.1.0.php`

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$entityType = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::class;
$productGroup = 'Prices';

$attributes = [
    'namespace_shipping_price' => [
        'type' => 'decimal',
        'label' => 'Shipping costs',
    ]
];

foreach ($attributes as $attributeName => $attribute) {
    $createdAttribute = $installer->addAttribute(
        $entityType,
        $attributeName,
        [
            'backend_type' => $attribute['type'],
            'label' => $attribute['label'],
            'group' => $productGroup,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ]
    );
}
```

I can't find anything in logs and also in core_resource the module is not available.

Comment: Do you see the module in Configuration > Advanced?

Comment: Yes, I can see the module in there

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have a totally different issue. When changing app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:424

```
if (!$this->_config->loadModulesCache()) {
```

To

```
if ($this->_config->loadModulesCache()) {
```

It does load. So I'm going to find out why my cache doesn't clear.

Comment: It is typically advised to manually clear cache after deploying a code change.